# How to download a rpm file and install it via Chef Recipe

Tags: chef-infra

I need to download several RPM files and install it via recipe. I am new to chef so this could be a very basic question

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far? Please show us your code. By using a search engine, you should be able to at least partially solve this problem.

Comment: Look into the rpm_package resource, https://docs.chef.io/resource_rpm_package.html

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Chef tutorial at https://learn.chef.io/. It covers the basics of Chef, including installing packages:

```
package %w{httpd mysql python}
```